# Ruby - Output file in CSV comes in one column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to print my values in CSV file like following where data is array of hashes.

UPDATES:

```
CSV.open(fn, "wb") do |csv|
 #first rows are always headers and the headers value is generated from the array of hashes
 data.each do |name, values|
    csv << [name, values.join(",")]
end
```

and values has data like : `true,false,false,false` and name is an array with data like: `light`.

But for some reason my columns are only 2 instead of 5. The values column is concatenated in one column.

How can I achieve multiple columns using above code ?

Comment: whoever has downvoted can you please explain the reason ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
CSV.open(fn, "wb") do |csv|
  data.each do |name, values|
    csv << [name, *values]
  end
end
```

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Array+to+Arguments+Conversion

Comment: one more question...I have row headers which needs to be converted as well...when I apply the same logic here; it doesnt work...csv << ['Names', *Headers.join(',')]...headers is an array...

Comment: If headers is the array with column names, just use csv << ['Names', *headers]

Comment: then the values in headers are like: ["John"], ["Peter"]....I dont want the brackets in them...

Comment: Add the headers information to the question, because I don't get the problem. It should work the same way.

Comment: Sorry. I don't understand. "headers is generated from the array of hashes". What does this mean? Can't you just show the headers value?